# AWS SNS to AWS apigateway integration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks, amazon-sns

My SNS Subscription shows "pending confirmation" to HTTPS protocol;
Architecture setup is like SNS publishes messages to Api gateway and the lambda proxy reads the SNS messages and prints it. Api gateway has 2 methods - POST and GET.

1. Where exactly can I read the messages published from SNS ?
2. Cloud watch console logs shows the messages which is triggered separately by api gateway, Unable to see and parse the messages pushed from SNS.

Comment: SNS allows you to invoke a Lambda directly with a message payload without going through the API Gateway. I'm not sure the point of the API Gateway, seems like its getting in the way. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html

Comment: SNS is from a different team and messages will be published to a webhook. Lambda was built, inorder to parse the messages from SNS.

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are facing?
Aren't the messages getting subscribed by the gateway?